# A property of Hilbert sphere

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, spherical-geometry

Let $X$ be (Edit: a closed convex subset of ) the unit sphere $Y=\{x\in \ell^2: \|x\|=1\}$ in $\ell^2$ with the great circle (geodesic) metric. (Edit: Suppose the diameter of $X$ is less than $\pi/2$.) Is it true that every decreasing sequence of nonempty closed convex sets in $X$ has a nonempty intersection? (A set $S$ is convex in $X$ if for every $x,y\in S$ the geodesic path between $x,y$ is contained in $S$.)

(I edited my original question.)

Comment: Please make your definition of a convex set more clearer.

Comment: @Muhammad. If $x\neq -y$, this means $x,y\in S$ implies $\cos(t)x+\sin(t)u \in S$ for $t$ between $0$ and $\cos^{-1}(x,y)$, where $u$ is the unit vector in the direction of $y-(x,y)x$, $(x,y)$ being the inner product of $x,y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, let $A_n$ be the subset of $X$ consisting of vectors that are zero in the first $n$ co-ordinates.

EDIT: this assumes that when $x$ and $y$ are antipodal, convexity of $S$ containing $x$, $y$ only requires that at least one of the great-circle paths is contained in $S$. If it requires all of them, then the $A_n$ are not convex. t.b. points out in the comments that in this case we can set $A_n$ to consist of all vectors in $X$ that are zero in the first $n$ co-ordinates and non-negative in the remainder.

Comment: Surely $A_n$ is not convex?  For instance, $A_1$ contains $(0,1,0,0,\dots)$ and $(0,-1,0,0,\dots)$ but not $(0,0,0,\dots)$.

Comment: @Nate: "convex" in this question means as a subset of the unit sphere, with respect to the geodesic metric. It's not yet clear how convexity works with antipodal points though.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks.

Comment: Chris: I think you can fix your example by requiring that all coordinates are non-negative. Then you avoid antipodal points.

Comment: @Eagle. I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: In fact, upon further thought, I realized that the only subsets of the unit sphere which are convex in my sense (two points are joined by a line segment) are singletons, since all points of the sphere are extreme points of the ball.  So that would make the problem trivial.

Comment: @Eldredge. See my comment above for Muhammad.

Comment: The answer to my edited question is true; see my post "Geometry of the Hilbert sphere" in Mathoverflow.